# Can't install NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

[Image of my terminal in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jlan.png)

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling node and clearing the cache but I can't seem to figure it out.  Any ideas?

I'm on Windows 10 if that helps

Comment: check the version of the module, request and node-sass

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

- Delete node_modules folder if you have one.
- Delete package.lock.json.
  Then...

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt upgrade`

`sudo apt install nodejs`

`npm install`

It seems that it's conflicting with chokidar.

Comment: OP is on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to delete node_modules and package-lock.json not package.json

and then add cmd

```
npm install --force
```

if you are using Ubuntu OS use

```
sudo npm install
```

Comment: Honestly wouldn't ever recommend using `sudo` to install a local project dependencies

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue before and I believe it has to do with your nodejs. I suggest you reinstall your node cause it might solve the issue.

Try purging it

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
```

Then remove dependencies

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then reinstall

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Also try updating your chokidar and axios to a newer version, yours is already depreciated.

Comment: The OP is on Windows.